# GA4 Custom report filter with 20 event names

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to create a reprort to show the 20 custom event triggers, I am trying to filter Matches Regex but looks like there is a character limit and it's only taking 9 of my event.

Any help on how to create this custom report? Really appreciate it

I created a custom report with a filer to match a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GA4  can support regular expressions with up to `256` characters. If your regular expression exceeds `256` characters, it won’t work.

**Alternative**

#1 Use Looker Studio and perform your data filtering there.

#2 Download the data in CSV/excel/g-sheet format and do the computation on those tools

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tushar, unfortunately I can only use the reporting on GA4